# Stopwatch go lang

Tags: go

i have a firewall that sends a discord webhook whenever an attack is detected and whenever the attack is no longer detected. I want to add something where it starts a stopwatch whenever it sends the webhook for attack detected. then stops the stopwatch whenever its no longer detected so that it sends how long the attack lasted in seconds with the no longer detected webhook.

This is for when its detected.

````
        fmt.Println("Rlimit Final", rLimit)
        cmd := exec.Command("php", "start.php", strconv.Itoa(reqs), strconv.Itoa(rps), strconv.Itoa(requested), strconv.Itoa(passedcaptcha), "ONLINE", "200", "FIREWALL")
        cmd.Run()```

/*and this is when it's no longer detected:*/
        if rps <= 20 && mitigation != 0 {
            cmd := exec.Command("php", "end.php", strconv.Itoa(totalreqs), strconv.Itoa(largerNumber), strconv.Itoa(totalver), strconv.Itoa(passedcaptcha), "ONLINE", "200", "FIREWALL")
            cmd.Run()
````

Comment: You can simply keep the time attack started, and the time it ends, and subtract the two.

Comment: As Burak said, you just store two times. There is no concept of a "stop watch" in software. You don't have to start any kind of clock, the system clock is always running and you just read the time as required.

Answer (score 2):

Could be something like this, as Burak suggested. Note, that it implies that you have only one firewall which can have only one attack, and the webhooks are located on the same instance, so the attackStartTime.tmp file is reachable for attackEnd.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    attackStart()
    time.Sleep(time.Second*3)
    attackEnd()
}

func attackStart()  {

    //... my cmd PHP code

    fileName := "/tmp/attackStartTime.tmp"
    timeAttackStarted := []byte(time.Now().Local().Format(time.RFC3339))

    if err := ioutil.WriteFile(fileName, timeAttackStarted, 0666); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}

func attackEnd() {
    
    //... my cmd PHP code
    fileName := "/tmp/attackStartTime.tmp"
    filecontent, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
    timeAttackEnded := time.Now().Local()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    timeAttackStarted, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, string(filecontent))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    duration := timeAttackEnded.Sub(timeAttackStarted)
    fmt.Printf("attack started at %v:\nattack ended: %v\nduration(seconds): %v\n",timeAttackStarted, timeAttackEnded, duration.Seconds())
}
```